# How to obtain a list of pairs of exponents in a double series expansion?

Tags: list-manipulation, series-expansion, exponent

Let's say we have a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ and we work out its Taylor expansion up to some power. I would like to use Mathematica to construct a list of all exponents that appear in the series. For example, if the series expansion yields something like

$$f(x,y) = xy^2+x^3y^5+xy^4+x^6y^4+O(x^7,y^6)$$

I would like to obtain the list `{{1,2}, {3,5}, {1,4}, {6,4}}`. Now, in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273459/how-to-get-the-exponents-of-a-polynomial-in-two-variables?rq=1) there is an explanation for polynomials. If `p` is such a polynomial,

```
Map[Exponent[#, {x,y}] &, List @@ p]
```

does the job. But for series it seems it's not working very well. For example, I considered the example

```
ser = Series[Hypergeometric2F1[a, a, b, x]*Hypergeometric2F1[c, c, d, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

Then `Map[Exponent[#, {x, y}] &, List @@ ser]` gives an error ("Objects of unequal length in `Exponent[...]` cannot be combined"). I then tried `Map[Exponent[#, {x, y}] &, List @@ ser[[3]]]` but then it simply gives a wrong result `{{0,2},{0,2},{0,2}}`, while the correct result would be `{{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}, {2,0}, {2,1}, {2,2}}`.

So it seems the method for polynomials in that thread to not work well for series.

In that case, given a series expansion in two variables in Mathematica, how can I construct a list of all pairs of exponents that appear in that expansion?

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@Map[Exponent[#, {x, y}] &, List @@ (ser // Normal // Expand)]`

Comment: Also: `Map[Exponent[#, {x, y}] &, Sort@MonomialList[Normal@ser, {x, y}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CoefficientRules`, `Normal` and `SortBy`:

```
rules = CoefficientRules[Normal@ser, {x, y}] /. Rule[x_, y_] :> x -> Simplify[y];

SortBy[rules, Last][[All, 1]]

(*{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}*)
```

Or using `MonomialList`:

```
Map[Exponent[#, {x, y}] &, Sort@MonomialList[Normal@ser, {x, y}]]

(*{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}*)
```